# Battery Simulation for each time step

Tags: python

i have following problem in python:
I want to simulate the behavior of a battery based on the second order Thevenin Model. To do so, i wanted to loop over a current_file which contains the current applied e.g. -3 Amps for 100 seconds, 0 amps for 200 seconds and so on. I then want to get the Parameters for the calculation, which i interpolated beforehand at the given position (Amp-Seconds) and the given temperature. With these Values, i then want to calculate the voltage drop across the rc branch 1 and 2 and with them, calculate the terminal voltage for this time step. After the first time step, the calculated values should be used as start values for the second cycle and so on, until the cycle is finished.
Sadly, i can´t see the behavior i want: When i apply for example -3 Amps for 10 seconds following 0 Amps for 100 seconds, i should see an exponential rise, but i only see a hard step. I don´t know what the problem is, i hope you can help me.

```
'''import the current_data file'''

current_file= pd.read_csv("current_input.csv", sep=";")
current_file.fillna(0, inplace=True) # none = 0

# Define simulation parameters
dt = 1
start_soc = 90
battery_capacity = 3320
start_position = -(1 - start_soc/100) * battery_capacity * 3.6
temp = 25


'''create the lists'''
results = pd.DataFrame()

'''create the loop'''
for n in range(len(current_file)):
    
    current = current_file["Current (A)"][n]

    if results.empty:
        time_interval = current_file["Time (sec)"][n]

    else:
        time_interval = abs(current_file["Time (sec)"][n] - current_file["Time (sec)"][n-1])
    steps = int(time_interval/dt)

    '''Solve the ODE for each timestep and loop over to the next one'''

        
    for i in range(steps):
        
        if results.empty:
            V0_initial = 0
            V1_initial = 1
            position = start_position

        '''get the parameters for the given position'''
        R0 = interpolator_R0(position,temp)
        R1 = interpolator_R1(position,temp)
        C0 = interpolator_C0(position,temp)
        C1 = interpolator_C1(position,temp)
        Rint = interpolator_Rint(position,temp)
        OCV = interpolator_ocv(position,temp)
        
        '''Solve for V0 and V1'''
        V0 = ((exp(-dt/R0*C0)*V0_initial)+
              R0*(1-exp(-dt/R0*C0)*current))
        
        V1 = ((exp(-dt/R1*C1)*V1_initial)+
              R1*(1-exp(-dt/R1*C1)*current))
        
        '''calculate the terminal Voltage'''
        Vt = OCV - Rint * current - V0 - V1
        end_position = position + (current* dt)

        results = results.append({
            "V0 (Volts)": V0,
            "V1 (Volts)": V1,
            "Vt (Volts)": Vt,
            "End Position": end_position
        }, ignore_index=True)
        
        position = end_position
        V0_initial = V0
        V1_initial = V1

# extract the time and voltage values from the results dataframe
time = results.index.values
voltage = results['Vt (Volts)'].values

# plot the voltage over time
plt.plot(time, voltage)
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Voltage (V)')
plt.title('Terminal voltage vs time')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the initial values before the loop:

```
    V0_initial = 0
    V1_initial = 0
    
    for i in range(steps):
        
        if results.empty:
            position = start_position
```

Comment: Hey angwrk, thanks for the reply but this sadly didn´t solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Feeling a bit stupid for answering my own question but i found the solution. The brackets in the functions itself were set wrong and the values V0 and V1 didn´t have to be updated.

> for n in range(len(current_file)):
> current = current_file["Current (A)"][n]/p
>
> ```
> if results.empty:
>     time_interval = current_file["Time (sec)"][n]
>     
> else:
>     time_interval = abs(current_file["Time (sec)"][n] - current_file["Time (sec)"][n-1])
>     
>     
> steps = int(time_interval/dt)
>
> '''Solve the ODE for each timestep and loop over to the next one'''
>
> for i in range(steps):
>     
>     '''if there is no result aka it´s the first cycle, use the start parameters, 
>     if there are none, extract the values from the previous cycle to calculate the new values'''
>     
>         
>     '''get the parameters for the given position'''
>     
>     R0 = get_battery_params(position,temp)["R0"]
>     R1 = get_battery_params(position,temp)["R1"]
>     C0 = get_battery_params(position,temp)["C0"]
>     C1 = get_battery_params(position,temp)["C1"]
>     Rint = get_battery_params(position,temp)["Rint"]
>     OCV = get_battery_params(position,temp)["OCV"]
>     
>     
>     '''Solve the ODE'''
>     V0 =(np.exp(-dt/(R0*C0)) * V0)+ R0 * (1-np.exp(-dt/(R0*C0)))*current
>     V1 = (np.exp(-dt/(R1*C1)) * V1)+ R1 * (1-np.exp(-dt/(R1*C1)))*current
>     
>     '''calculate the terminal Voltage'''
>     Vt = (OCV - Rint * current - V0 - V1)*s
>     Ploss = abs((OCV*s-Vt)*current*p)
>     end_position = position + (current*dt)
>
>     new_row = {
>         "V0 (Volts)": V0,
>         "V1 (Volts)": V1,
>         "Vt (Volts)": Vt,
>         "End Position": end_position,
>         "OCV (Volts)": OCV,
>         "Ploss": Ploss
>     }
>     
>     results = pd.concat([results, pd.DataFrame([new_row])], ignore_index=True)
>     position = end_position
> ```